# Apache: %25 in url (400 Bad Request)

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

I have a url containing the following:

```
/somepath/morestuff/ohno%25foobar
```

For some reason apache is reporting a 400 bad request (it has something to do with the %25). I am using mod_rewrite to rewrite the path to point to my codeigniter instance but it's not even getting to codeigniter, it's just the default apache error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason you need `%25`?  `%25` is the code for a `%` sign.

Comment: @Bemrose, it's actually for an api where people could post any string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that you're using `PATH_INFO` to handle your CodeIgniter requests. Consequently, your `.htaccess` file contains a rule set that looks similar to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

When `mod_rewrite` tests your URLs, they have already been decoded to their natural character format, so in this case `%25` has become just `%`. When you apply this rule, the backreference actually contains the literal text `somepath/morestuff/ohno%foobar`, which is *not* re-encoded by default. Apache has no idea what that `%` is doing in your request path to `/index.php/somepath/morestuff/ohno%foobar` and chokes, giving you that error.

If you're running Apache 2.2, `mod_rewrite` added the `B` flag for this purpose, allowing you to automatically escape backreferences rewritten to your URL. Adding it to your current flag list should fix the problem in that case:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0 [B,L]
```

There's also an `escape` [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) that's available as an internal map in previous Apache versions of `mod_rewrite`, but unfortunately this map has to be enabled at the server or virtual server configuration level, so may not be available if you're running your site on shared hosting. It does the same thing, though a bit more deliberately.

In your server/virtual server configuration:

```
RewriteMap escape int:escape
```

Then, wherever you define your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/${escape:$0} [L]
```

Keep in mind that CodeIgniter doesn't need to use `PATH_INFO` to get the request information, and using `REQUEST_URI` is perfectly acceptable here if you aren't using `mod_rewrite` to do any other transformations (and would avoid this headache altogether). I think by default CodeIgniter is set to get the request from `AUTO` (assuming I haven't gotten my frameworks mixed up), so simply not rewriting the request to the URL with path info would be enough to make that change.

Comment: I'm running apache 2.2 but that B flag didn't work... it caused a 500.

Comment: @Ken Struys - What does your error log have to say about the 500?

Comment: says the B flag is unknown. I'm running 2.2.3 and 2.2.7 added the B flag. I do have full access to the server (not shared hosting) so I can do whatever I need to do to apache.

Comment: @Ken Struys - Looking at the change log for 2.2, someone apparently broke the `B` flag at some point, and it wasn't fixed until 2.2.12. You can recompile `mod_rewrite` with the [latest source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c) or update Apache, but both of those might be more trouble than they're worth, so I've expanded on how to define the `RewriteMap` if you'd like to try using that first.

Comment: I got it working using escape. initially it wasn't working because codeigniter by default auto doesn't use the REQUEST_URI it does some weird automatic detection. When is switch it over to REQUEST_URI in the config everything worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a great tip, TIM, and one I have been seeking for a while.

Comment: I also found that changing my config uri_protocol from PATH_INFO to AUTO solved this. Took your suggestion for me to find that, but got it working. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 2):

Apache 2.2.12+, just use the `B` flag.  Otherwise, see here:

http://www.dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/

Answer (score 1):

In jquery before setting to url you have to encode like this
this will encode % and / both.....
"**encodeURI(encodeURI(encodeURIComponent('your string')));**"

on php or view page you have to decode like following

**urldecode(urldecode(htmlspecialchars('your encoded string', ENT_QUOTES)))**