# 400 Bad Request when URL contains %25

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am using CakePHP and am facing the issue only with %25 encoded character. For other escaped symbols like %22 etc the URL rewriting seems to be perfectly fine.

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549747/apache-25-in-url-400-bad-request) reports similar problem with CodeIgniter but the solution is something that cannot be directly applied to my use case as the ModRewrite rules are not the same.

Can someone please help me with equivalent changes in CakePHP changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using mod_security? I vaguely remember having a similar problem that was related to that apache module - disabling it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same solution as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549747/apache-25-in-url-400-bad-request), but maintain the `QSA` part:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,B,L]
</IfModule>
```