# Why does this URL cause a bad request on my server?

Tags: url, character-encoding, urlencode, bad-request

I have a URL which ends with a `%`. Like: `/view/this-is-100%25`. Is it not allowed to have `%` at the end of a URL? If it's not allowed how can I do it in another way and if it's allowed, why does it cause a bad request?

Thanks.

update: exact error:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Comment: This may help: [Apache: %25 in url (400 Bad Request)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549747/apache-25-in-url-400-bad-request)

Comment: What server is serving your pages?

Comment: @SamRad as this was the case only in 1 URL, I solved it using str_replace placing it with "percent" and on the server changing it back to "%". Ugly solution, but in my case sufficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this problem by replacing `%` with `percent`, because this was only the case in one of my URLs. For a better solution see this link Sam Rad provided my the first comment on my post: 
[Apache: %25 in url (400 Bad Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549747/apache-25-in-url-400-bad-request)

Answer (score 1):

"%" is used in URLs as a prefix for an ASCII (?) UTF-8(?) code. For example a "space" (ASCII 32 or hex 0x20) can be substituted as "%20". The "%" prefix is followed by two hex digits. The web server should take the "%20" and convert it to a space.

When you have a "%" at the end of a URL, you do not have two hex digits following the "%", so the substitution cannot be done, and the URL is in-fact malformed. It is actually a bad URL.

This is why the server doesn't like it.

Comment: He has `%25`, not `%`.. well you assume he literally has `%`, whereas he means he has properly encoded `%` as `%25` and it still doesn't work...