# %25 in being appended in htaccess redirected Url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

i am tried o redirect all non https url to http so i am using this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [B,R,L]
```

but when i remove https from url for testing , it redirect to https but it goes to `https://example.com/%25myfile.php`

that `%25` is being added in url and making link NOT FOUND . am i making some mistake in above? I followed [Apache: %25 in url (400 Bad Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549747/apache-25-in-url-400-bad-request) and added flag B as shown in above code but it not work .

Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

- `NE` flag prevents encoding special characters.
- `%{REQUEST_URI}` uses original URI not relative to current directory.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing the change.

Comment: Thank you , that did the job :)